# Stack Overflow Database - Pairs of users systematically comment the same posts

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am working on the stack overflow database (https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) and I would like to know which pairs of users systematically comment the same posts? (There are not any posts where 1 of 2 users have written a comment)

I have make this query (I took the first 10) but it doesn't return the good result :

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 c1.userId, u1.displayName, c2.userId, u2.displayName
FROM comments AS c1
JOIN users AS u1 ON (c1.userId = u1.id)
,comments AS c2
JOIN users AS u2 ON (c2.userId = u2.id)
WHERE c1.postId = c2.postId
AND c1.userId != c2.userId
AND c1.postId = ALL(SELECT postId FROM comments AS c3 WHERE c3.userId=c2.userId)
GROUP BY c1.userId, u1.displayName, c2.userId, u2.displayName
```

Result of this query :

[image: result of query]

I don't know what is wrong with my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join conditions are a bit convoluted.  You want to be sure the two comments are on the same point, so include that in the `ON` clause.  Then, you are also\ missing an `order by`:

```
SELECT TOP 10 c1.userId, u1.displayName, c2.userId, u2.displayName, COUNT(*)
FROM comments AS c1 JOIN
     users AS u1
     ON c1.userId = u1.id join
     comments AS c2
     ON c1.postId = c2.postId JOIN
     users AS u2
     ON c2.userId = u2.id AND
        c2.userId < c1.userId
GROUP BY c1.userId, u1.displayName, c2.userId, u2.displayName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

The `<` is to avoid duplicate pairs.

Comment: this query produces symmetric pairs.. maybe use `c2.userid < c1.userid` or `c2.userid > c1.userid`

Comment: @vkp . . . Good suggestion.  I made that change.